# Select Html en JSP

Tags: jsp

Tengo en la página listado.jsp una lista de usuarios que los saco de un linkedlist

```
 <form name="formsendmessage" action="../mipagina.jsp"  method="POST">

        <select multiple> <%
                          LinkedList list = (LinkedList) session.getAttribute("emailusers");
                          for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) { %>
                          <option name="listemails[]" value="<%=list.get(i) %>"><%=list.get(i) %></option>
                          <% }  %>  

                         </select>
                         <input type="submit" name="btnsendmessage" value="Send Answer">  
                </form>
```

Y en mi pagina.jsp

```
<% String [] listemails = request.getParameterValues("listemails[]");

            for (int i = 0; i < listemails.length; i++) {
                out.println(listemails[i]);
             } %>
```

Antes cuando los mostraba con `<input type="check" name="listemails[]">` funcionaba perfectamente, pero ahora no, qué problema hay ??

Comment: Te sale algún error o aviso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El nombre del select va en la etiqueta de apertura de este:

```
        <form name="formsendmessage" action="../mipagina.jsp"  method="POST">

            <select name="listemails[]"> <% /*Aquí va el name (nombre)*/
                  LinkedList list = (LinkedList) session.getAttribute("emailusers"); 
                  for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) { %>
                  <option  value="<%=list.get(i) %>"><%=list.get(i) %></option>
                  <% }  %>  

            </select>
            <input type="submit" name="btnsendmessage" value="Send Answer">  
        </form>
```

Para obtener el valor seleccionado de un select se utiliza `request.getParameter("nombreDelSelect");`
y este solo devuelve un String, es decir que no necesita un arreglo.

```
        <% String emailSeleccionado = request.getParameter("listemails[]");/*Manera correcta*/

              out.println(emailSeleccionado);

        %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Gracias, ya lo conseguí de la siguiente forma:

```
 <select multiple name="listemails[]">

                      <%
                          LinkedList list = (LinkedList) session.getAttribute("emailusers");
                          for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) { %>
                          <option value="<%=list.get(i) %>"><%=list.get(i) %></option>
                          <% }  %>  

                         </select>
```

Y para mostrar los seleccionados :

```
 String[] listemails = request.getParameterValues("listemails[]");

        for (int i = 0; i < listemails.length; i++) {
            out.println(listemails[i]);
         }
```

Se necesita el getParameterValues . Por si se devuelven varios valores.
Gracias.